# How to formalize sentence constraints for Z3 SMT Solver (for Python)

Tags: python, logic, solver, smt, z3py

I am a Psychology grad trying to change path to Data Science and I have a tough time wrapping my head around this problem for Artificial Intelligence course at my university. I don't really know how to formalize those sentences, except for First-Order Logic, but I was told by my teacher that does not work because of the predicates with the Z3 solver.

Hard constraints:
• A teacher could not attend two classes at the same time.
• A teacher teaches only one course at each timeslot.
• All classes should be after 14:40.
Soft constraints:
• The classes should be scheduled in such a way to avoid having classes on weekends.
• There should be at most 3 classes per student daily.
• Most classes should be after 16:10.
• Some professors do not prefer classes in late evening, after 19:30.

I tried something like this but not sure if it is ok:

```
Hard constraints:
• A Professor could not attend two classes at the same time.
∀p∃c(c=1)
• A Professor teaches only one course at each timeslot.
∀c∃t(p=1)
• All classes should be after 14:40.
∀c(t>h1) - h1 being the timeslot
Soft constraints:
• The classes should be scheduled in such a way to avoid having classes on weekends.
∀c(d=[d1:d5])
• There should be at most 3 classes per student daily.
∀s(c=<3)
• Most classes should be after 16:10.
∀c(t=[h2:])
• Some professors do not prefer classes in late evening, after 19:30.
∃p(OR(t=h2,t=h3))
```

Comment: How you model this in z3 really depends on a myriad of factors: Are there a fixed number of classes/professors? Or do you want to model a fixed known set?  An array is the simplest to work, but that'd require quantification which usually doesn't work well with SMT solvers.  Without answering these questions, it's hard to opine on what would be the best approach. Start by reviewing https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~agurfink/ece653w17/assets/pdf/W06-FOLSMT.pdf which will give you some ideas on how to go about doing so. (Especially the last third of the slide-deck.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.